# Does porting Android application to BB 10 causes performance issues?

Tags: android, blackberry, porting, blackberry-10

I am very new to BlackBerry 10 development. Reading some of the documents I could understand that it is possible to port Android applications to BB 10. In fact it is the only way one can develop apps for BB 10 using JAVA language.

I really wonder porting the apps will ever cause any performance issues in BB 10. My client is very particular about the performance of the application which we are developing.

Can any of the experts here tell me whether there is a chance that the ported application be slow in BB 10?

Thank you in advance.
Awaiting your reply

Jayakrishnan Salim

Comment: Can you explain which part of your app is performance-sensitive?  Does it play video?  Is it a game, with complicated graphics?  Lots of network activity?  Please be specific.

Comment: Like @Nate said, depends on what the app does. Also you must know that with BlackBerry 10.2 update Android 4.2 will be supported, and hardware acceleration.

Comment: My application has many network calls and DB operations. It doesn't have any video playback or complicated graphics. Its something similar to FB application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the performance, no issue is to be reported. It works just fine, as on a mid-end Android 2.3 device. However, not that not every application can be ported, some restrictions applies: in particular, your application can't contain native (C/C++) code.

Comment: I read somewhere that the DB operations in ported apps can be a bit slow compared to the performance in Android version. Is there anything which we can do to speed it up?