# Is there any drawbacks using android repackaging tools for blackberry app Development?

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have expertise in Android App development. And now I want to develop an app on BlackBerry-10. I have gone through this page: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/. Are there any drawbacks using this or is this technique as efficient as the BlackBerry development using Java. Please help?

Comment: This is the best (albeit, only) way to get your Android app on BB10. If you wanted to, you could use the native "Cascades" SDK and build a more native app, but if you prefer to stick with Android code, that's the way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is confusion here regarding the various BB platforms and what is supported on each.

BB10 phones support Android runtime, and do not support Java.

BB7 phones (the older phones) support Java but do not support Android Runtime.

Assuming you only want to develop for BB10 (Z10, Q10, Q5, ...), then in fact you can probably do most things you want to do.  See this page:

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/

for the not supported APIs.  Check that out, if you think your app will work fine, then you might as well continue working in Android.

Be aware that you will get negative reviews for not having a native application.  Personally I think this is silly - the important thing is the application's functionality, not how it was written.  If you wanted to start developing in 'native', then you need to swap to C++ and Cascades.

At this time I would not recommend attempting to learn BB7 Java.  It will take you as long to get the hang of it as C++/Cascades, and though BBRY are still releasing new phones for this OS, they are also trying to migrate people to BB10.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The important thing is not only the application's functionality. Ported Android applications sucks. It's an efficient temporary solution, but it lacks platform integration, performance, and looks ugly compared to native apps.

Comment: @Kernald - your opinion is noted, but it is just an opinion. My opinion is different.  For me, not all apps need platform integration, I don't understand your comment regarding performance when you said performance was fine for Android apps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101238/does-porting-android-application-to-bb-10-causes-performance-issues/18103339#18103339, and looks are in the eye of the beholder.  Functionality is most  important - if an app does what they want it to do, then users will be happy, and won't care what it is written in.  That is my opinion anyway.

Comment: Performance is perfectly acceptable in the way that most apps works better on my Z10 (in 10.2, so with the Android 4.2 runtime, it wasn't as good with the 2.3 runtime) than they do on my HTC Sensation (nearly the same CPU, same Android version). However, they are miles away from native ones. As an user, I disagree with your two last sentences for this reason, and for the lack of UI consistency between Android apps.